# Get the span with content using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this html

```
<span style="font-size:20px">
    <span style="font-family:verdana">Text 1</span>
</span>
<span style="font-size:11px">
    <span style="fontfamily:arial">Text 2</span>
</span>
```

I want to get span elements that have content

```
<span style="fontfamily:arial">Text 2</span>
<span style="font-family:verdana">Text 1</span>
```

I'm using JSoup and here are my tries

```
doc.select("span[text!=\"\"]")
doc.select("span[text]")
doc.select("span[content]")
doc.getElementsByTag("span").stream().filter(p -> p.hasText())
```

Coul anyone helps me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can't you just do `span span` if there's always two levels of nesting?? The selector syntax you're trying to use doesn't exist in Jsoup, see the documentation here: [Jsoup Selector](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: @zack6849 I can't use ´span span´, it is not always two levels of nesting. I didn't find anything like that in the documentation

Comment: does the text you want always match a certain pattern or something?

Comment: @zack6849 no, it's a field and the user can write anything he wants and format the text the same way

Comment: @zack6849 i found a way in the docs. It's 'span:only-child'. Thank you

Comment: @Renato Ramos Nascimento, :only-child  elements that have a parent element and whose parent element hasve no other element children, but you already say it is not always two levels of nesting. Confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you want to select spans which should have text between that span, you may easily filter all the spans by using: Element.ownText​() is not empty. See:
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--

`public String ownText​()
Gets the text owned by this element only; does not get the combined text of all children.`